# Stop YouTube api from launching on page load

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, web-inspector

Right now, when the page loads, the YouTube api is launched right away.

How do I set it up so that the YouTube api doesn't launch until the play svg image is clicked?

Is there anyone who knows how this would be done?

Has this question been answered already? I didn't see it so I am asking it here.

https://jsfiddle.net/182tL0f5/

```
  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

[image]

**I'm trying to achieve this:**

[image]

Comment: Scripts are immediately executed when the corresponding `<script>`s are appended to the document. So just don't append the `<script>` containing API calls before the image is clicked.

Comment: What do you mean, and how would I implement that in my code? I don't know how to do that with my code.

Comment: How do I do what you are suggesting? "This? So just don't append the <script> containing API calls before the image is clicked."

Comment: How would it be done in the code,? https://jsfiddle.net/182tL0f5/ Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, can you show me?

Comment: Take your jsfiddle as an example. Move those codes responsible for the creation of the `<script>` into the click event handler will do. Namely, cut the codes from line 41 to 44, and paste them after line 28.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know how to do it. https://jsfiddle.net/L4xtwy1r/

Comment: @Microloft How would I do that if 3 videos are being used instead of 1? https://jsfiddle.net/0nhgax6t/

Comment: They share the same API, so the script only needs to be loaded once. After the script loaded by the first video, it can not be undone.

Comment: Where would I move the <script> into What click event handler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820649/prevent-youtube-api-from-starting-when-more-than-1-player-is-being-used-in-the-j Would I create a new one?

Comment: The easiest way is using a global variable as a flag and deciding whether the `coverClickHandler` should load the script depending on that flag.

Comment: I don't know how to implement that, can you show me how?

Comment: What do you mean? Just check the flag in the `coverClickHandler`. If the flag is set, skip the loading process. If the flag is not set, load the script and set it after loading. We should only point the way or give advices. Please do not rely on others doing the actual work.

Comment: I almost got it to work here, but not all the videos play. https://jsfiddle.net/xpo7wr63/ How would I fix that?

Comment: What do I need to do to get it to work, I was able to get that far? I was almost able to do it.

Comment: Is this something that is achievable, or it's not?

Comment: I'm starting to think that this can't be done and is impossible to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236222/discussion-between-csshtmljavascript14578-and-microloft).

Comment: The problem of your current code is that `coverClickHandler` in `loadPlayer` is registered **AFTER** the first clicking, so the first clicked cover itself won't be triggered. That is why the first clicked cover always behaves weirdly. As I said earlier, you can use a global variable to act as a flag. There is a functional [example](https://jsfiddle.net/c5morw27/). I only made minimum modification to your original code. Please note that it is just a quick fix, not the best way to doing things. You should really revise the whole structure.

Comment: After doing what you said I updated the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/n5gutL8x/ With your code added to it, how come none of the buttons are clickable? Meaning none of the videos open up when clicked on? Working version with your code not added to it: https://jsfiddle.net/t4yu51fn/ All the buttons open and play.

Comment: I am not going to debug every version of your code. I already provided you a working example. Please start from there and check what modification you made causes the issue step by step.